# Fetch JSON Data from SQLite and populate into ListView

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, listview

I have written a program in which i am parsing JSON and then storing JSON Data into SQLite, but here i need your guidance to show data into List using SQLite.

Now whenever i do close Internet Connection would not getting data into list, please let me know what code i need to use in my DatabaseHelper class to get all records and what are the changes need to apply in MainActivity to show that code into ListView.

see my below code which i am using to store data into database, **DatabaseHelper.java**:-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "storeJSON";
    // Table Name
    private static final String TABLE_MEMBER = "churchResults";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Create Table Name
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_MEMBER + 
                  "(Id VARCHAR(100)," +
                  " Title VARCHAR(100));");

        Log.d("CREATE TABLE","Create Table Successfully");
    }

    // Insert Data
    public long InsertData(String strId, String strTitle) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("Id", strId); 
            Val.put("Title", strTitle);

            long rows = db.insert(TABLE_MEMBER, null, Val);

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows inserted.

         } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
         }
    }

    // Update Data
    public long UpdateData(String strId, String strTitle){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = this.getWritableDatabase(); // Write Data

            ContentValues Val = new ContentValues();
            Val.put("Id", strId);
            Val.put("Title", strTitle);

            long rows = db.update(TABLE_MEMBER, Val, "Id=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(strId) });

            db.close();
            return rows; // return rows updated.

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return -1;
        }   
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_MEMBER);
        // Re Create on method  onCreate
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

and activity code, which i am using to show data into ListView, **MainActivity.java:-**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 //  initialize databaseHelper object in oncreate of Activity before using it
        dHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MainActivity.this);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Creating JSON Parser instance
        jParser = new JSONParser();

        // getting JSON string from URL
        jObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        try {
            // Getting Array of events
            jArray = jObject.getJSONArray(TAG_CHURCH);

            // looping through All events
            for(int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                strId = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                Log.d("strId :: --", strId);
                strTitle = c.getString(TAG_TITLE);
                Log.d("strTitle :: --", strTitle);

                dHelper.InsertData(strId, strTitle);

                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, strId);
                map.put(TAG_TITLE, strTitle);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
                R.layout.activity_list,
                new String[] { TAG_TITLE }, new int[] {
                        R.id.title });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        final ListView lv = getListView();

        // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long iD) {
                strId = contactList.get(position).get(TAG_ID);
                Log.d("strId-onItemClick :: --", strId);
                strTitle = contactList.get(position).get(TAG_TITLE);
                Log.d("strTitle-onItemClick :: --", strTitle);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Id-"+strId+"Title-"+strTitle, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        });     
    }
```

Comment: fetch your data into cursor and use cursor adapter to populate data into listview

Comment: @r4jiv007 can you show me the way how can i implement cursor in my existing program to populate data into listview ?

Comment: http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/